# Update Manager downloaded updates but can't install them

Tags: 11.10, updates, update-manager

I am using 11.10 and have some problems with Update manager.
When I opening `Update manager` it's saying that I have some updates to install.

[image: Update Manager]

When I press button `Install Updates`, `Update manager` brings the following window:

[image: Update problem]

My software sources settings is:

[image: Other Software]

Can anyone say what is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `cdrom:Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release` from the *Other Software*  and try again.

Since you are currently using 11.10, I reckon that entry is conflicting and interrupting your updating process.

[image]